# Ansible sysctl setting bridge-nf-call-iptables failed: sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/bridge-nf-call-iptables: No such file or directory

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible in CentOS 7 and trying to set the kernel setting but it's giving an error.

Ansible version 2.3.0.0.

Here is the value I am trying to change:

```
 - name: update kernel settings
       sysctl:
         name: bridge-nf-call-iptables
         value: 1
         sysctl_set: yes
         state: present
         reload: yes
```

the file is in this path `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables`, but Ansible is looking at in `/proc/sys/bridge-nf-call-iptables`.

How can I fix this error?

> setting bridge-nf-call-iptables failed: sysctl: cannot stat
>   /proc/sys/bridge-nf-call-iptables: No such file or directory

Comment: Dont you need to use `become`?

Comment: @Kyslik didn't see that option in the doc. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/sysctl_module.html

Comment: Its not an option, its base functionality how to use module as sudo user, not sure about your distribution, if its required; its a long shot anyway. You pointed out that Ansible is looking in wrong directory so probably just troubleshoot via github issues.

Comment: oh. I am running the script as root user. this option is not needed in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [`sysctl` module manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/sysctl_module.html):

> `name` - The dot-separated path (aka key) specifying the sysctl variable.

So you need to specify:

```
- name: update kernel settings
  become: yes
  sysctl:
    name: net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables
    value: 1
    sysctl_set: yes
    state: present
    reload: yes
```

<sup>I added `become` explicitly to avoid confusion.</sup>
<sup>The code in your question is also incorrectly indented.</sup>